# Chrome Driver works but issues with GeckoDriver

Tags: python-3.x, selenium, geckodriver

I am writing a script to download files for a project I'm working on.  My company blocks the site on Chrome, but not with FireFox, so I decided to give Geckodriver a try, but keep running into this issue:

```
AttributeError: module 'selenium.webdriver' has no attribute 'FireFox'
```

Here's my code:

```
import selenium.webdriver as webdriver
from selenium.webdriver import firefox
import os

def init_driver():
    driver = 
webdriver.FireFox(r"C:\Users\Michael.Spencer\Documents\geckodriver.exe")
    driver.wait = webdriver.support.ui.WebDriverWait(driver, 5)
    return driver

def download(driver):

    driver.get("http://www.google.com")

def main():
    driver = init_driver()
    download(driver)
    driver.close()

main()
```

This works fine if I use

```
webdrive.Chrome(r"C:\Users\Michael.Spencer\Documents\chromedriver.exe")
```

Firefox even pops up when I start typing, so at this point I am not sure how to proceed.

[image]

Comment: Can you try changing your two import statements to `from selenium import webdriver`?

Comment: I sent the script to my personal computer via gmail and it worked perfectly when copy and pasted into notepad++. However if I delete the driver = webdriver.FireFox() line, and retype it I get the same attribute error.  I've tried converting spaces to tabs, and tabs to spaces, makes no difference.  This seems like very odd behavior and this attribute error seems to be incorrect as it works fine when copy and pasted.  Could it be  the version of selenium (3.4.3) I am running is not in sync with my version of FireFox (54.0.1)?

Comment: Chrome(), Ie(), and PhantomJS(), all work, so I'm guessing FireFox.() is currently going through some bug fixes as it transitions to geckodriver.exe?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

try this, I may be wrong, but it could be the way you are importing

```
from selenium import webdriver
driver = webdriver.Firefox()
```

Comment: I can do  from "selenium.webdriver import firefox".  But I am still thrown the same error when I try webdriver.FireFox(r'C:\my\path\geckodrive.exe').  So is there a different name I should be using other than "FireFox"?

Comment: Interesting! when i copied your code to my IDE, it gave me the same error you are facing. so removed all the imports and had typed 'from selenium import webdriver', still the same error. Then removed webdriver.Firefox line and typed again, the error went off. I dont know why it behaved in that fashion, but you can try that

Comment: Adding geckodriver to Anaconda>>Library>>bin, seemed to help.  I now get this Error: WebDriverException: Unable to find a matching set of capabilities.  Which may have to do with my companies proxy, I'll have to try the script on my home computer. It's interesting that chromedriver.exe can be anywhere as long as you specify the path, but geckodriver.exe cannot.